# bash command not found, or other workaround?

Tags: php, bash, terminal, yii

I'm working with the book Agile Web Development with Yii. In Chapter 8, it creates a php script to set up a RBAC (role based access control) so that when we access the shell at

```
/framework/yiic shell
```

it should allow us to enter a command

```
rbac
```

Pursuant to the PHP script that we created, the command creates three roles, Owner, Member and Reader with various permissions.

My problem is that, working with MAMP, when I do the command

```
yiic shell
```

it says

`-bash: yiic: command not found`

Therefore, I can't create these roles, and then I can't continue along with the book, because I don't know any work around

Can anyone help?

UPDATE
pursuant to one of the answers below, I did `chmod +x yiic`

Now when I run `/framework/yiic shell` it seems to enter the shell but not the same one described by my book

The book tells me I should get this

```
    % YiiRoot/framework/yiic shell Yii Interactive Tool v1.1 (based on Yii v1.1.2) Please type 'help' for help. Type 'exit' to quit. >>
    Now type help to see a list of available commands:
 >> help
    At the prompt, you may enter a PHP statement or one of the following commands:
    - controller
 - crud 
- form
 - help

    - model
 - module 
- rbac
    Type 'help <command-name>' for details about a command.
```

However, I'm getting

```
USAGE
  yiic shell [entry-script | config-file]

DESCRIPTION
  This command allows you to interact with a Web application
  on the command line. It also provides tools to automatically
  generate new controllers, views and data models.

  It is recommended that you execute this command under
  the directory that contains the entry script file of
  the Web application.

PARAMETERS
 * entry-script | config-file: optional, the path to
   the entry script file or the configuration file for
   the Web application. If not given, it is assumed to be
   the 'index.php' file under the current directory.
```

Comment: I don't know a great deal about this kind of thing but you might need to add the yii directory into your $PATH in your bash profile.

Comment: @sehe , I typed config-file and it said "command not found" do you know how I'm supposed to specify these paramaters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the full path:

`/framework/yiic shell`

You have to add `/framework/` to your `$PATH`-environment variable if you want to use `yiic` without giving the full path.

Comment: I tried that from both within the framework directory and also within htdocs (which contains framework) and I got "No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you check with `ls /framework/` if the file is in the folder and if it is executable? `chmod +x /framework/yiic`

Comment: @cularis, I did what you suggested and it opens a shell, but not the same one described by the book. i.e. it doesn't offer me the commands I'm looking for. Please see my update in OP if you can assist some more.

Comment: @Michael You have to add the entry-script or config-file as an argument or start the shell in the directory where your entry-script or config-file are.

Comment: You created a PHP-File for this tutorial? Specify its path after `yiic shell`. e.g. `yiic shell /home/user/mywebapp.php`

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the path:

```
/framework/yiic
```

or include the directory in your PATH

```
PATH="$PATH:/framework"
export PATH
```

Comment: I'd include it where you need it. Only. Also, in bash you can `export PATH="$PATH:/framework"` in one go

Comment: after changing permissions on the yiic shell to make it executable, I can now access ./yiic shell however it doesn't open the same shell as described by my book. i.e it doesn't give me the commands I need like crud and rbac. Please see update in my OP if you can help more